# How to start service at boot on android 4.0.3

Tags: android

I wan't to start service at boot on android 4.0.3 but when i boot my device it not happen in my device and service not start.Help me please thank you

here is my manifest

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.android.testsharedpreference.MyService"></service>

    <receiver android:name="com.android.testsharedpreference.BootReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

my boardcast receiver

```
    public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) 
            {
             context.startService(new Intent(context,MyService.class));
            }
        }
    }
```

and my service

```
     public class MyService extends Service
     {
          @Override
          public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
          {
             return null;
          }

          @Override
          public void onCreate() 
          {
               super.onCreate();
              Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "onCreate Service ",                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }

          @Override
          public void onDestroy() 
          {
             super.onDestroy();
             Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "onDestroy Service ",                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
        }
```

Comment: Have you started your Main Activity? Apps don't register receivers until started.

Comment: I started my Main Activity but how i can register receiver on my Main Activity

Comment: A freshly installed app on ICS does not install the `receiver`s you define in the Manifest until the app is run (it's in "stopped" state). You don't need to do anything besides running the app. See http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols

Comment: thank a lot but how i can add flag FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES in my code

Comment: you can't that flag is set for `Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` so that this Intent will only reach started apps.

Comment: if i can not set for Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED how i can implement to start service at boot ?

Comment: The user must launch your app from the launcher before you will be able to receive `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcasts.

Comment: It mean no way to start a service when device is boot.Only way to start service is launched by user ?

Comment: A user needs to start your app once. If he gets it from the market but never starts it then you don't get the broadcast. If he tries out your app just one time then you will.

Comment: anyone show an example for me please

Answer (score 2):

you should add `add android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` as it was not required before ICS so the app was working fine but starting from ICS is you don't have this permission your app wont receive the boot completed intent

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to override the method "onStartCommand" in your MyService:

```
    @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    String action = intent == null ? null : intent.getAction();
    Log.d("onStartCommand", "action = " + action);
    /* ... */
    return START_NOT_STICKY; // for example ...
}
```